# How to add javascript upon ajax response rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add Ajax, so far I am able to add a javascript response, however I can't add a template.

Here my javascript

### application.js

```
$("#new_role").on("ajax:success", function (e, data, status, xhr) 
{
    $("#newRoleForm").hide(1000);
    return;
}).bind("ajax:error", function (e, xhr, status, error) 
{
    return alert("Error");
});
```

Here my controller

```
  def create
    @role = Role.new(params[:role])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @role.save
        format.html { redirect_to roles_path, notice: 'Role was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @role, status: :created, location: @role }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @role.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Now i see a lots of comment stating I should add create.js.erb, but if i just create one and place alert(...); It does get executed. I have modified my form to be ajax remote => true. But i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are asking here, but if you want Rails to respond with javascript (a very powerful feature of rails), in the above example add something like:

```
format.js { render 'create' }
```

Then put a create.js.erb file in the appropriate folder. (probably 'roles'). Here you can update your dom, etc. using javascript/jquery with the help of rails. The advantage is that you have access to all of your helpers and partials!